# Javascript Form Select Change Options Dynamic List Error

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select

The only issue I am having with the below is that the first dropdown does not display the the Faculty Name on the first dropdown. However, when selected (first blank option) it returns the schools from that particular faculty. I have a feeling it's something very minor so any feedback would be appreciated.

```js
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  if (s1.value == "Faculty of Arts, Humanities and Social Sciences") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "schoolOfArt|School of Art", "schoolOfArtsAndHumanities|School of Arts and Humanities", "schoolOfCommunicationAndMedia|School of Communication and Media", "schoolOfEducation|School of Education", "schoolOfLaw|School of Law", "schoolOfAppliedSocialAndPolicySciences|School of Applied Social and Policy Sciences"];

  } else if (s1.value == "Faculty of Computing, Engineering and the Built Environment") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "schoolOfComputing|School of Computing", "schoolOfComputingEngineeringAndIntelligentSystems|School of Computing, Engineering and Intelligent Systems", "schoolOfEngineering|School of Engineering", "School of Architecture and the Built Environment|schoolOfArchitectureAndTheBuiltEnvironment"];

  } else if (s1.value == "Faculty of Life & Health Sciences") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "schoolOfBiomedicalSciences|School of Biomedical Sciences", "schoolOfGeographyEnvironmentalSciences|School of Geography & Environmental Sciences", "schoolOfHealthSciences|School of Health Sciences", "schoolOfNursing|School of Nursing", "schoolOfPharmacyAndPharmaceuticalSciences|School of Pharmacy & Pharmaceutical Sciences", "schoolOfPsychology|School of Psychology", "schoolOfSport|School of Sport"];

  } else if (s1.value == "Ulster University Business School") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "departmentOfAccountingFinanceAndEconomics|Department of Accounting, Finance and Economics", "departmentOfGlobalBusinessAndEnterprise|Department of Global Business and Enterprise", "departmentOfHospitalityTourismManagement|Department of Hospitality & Tourism Management", "departmentOfManagementLeadershipAndMarketing|Department of Management, Leadership and Marketing"];
  }

  for (var option in optionArray) {
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Select your Faculty:</h2>
  <hr/> Choose Faculty:
  <select id="select1" name="select1" onchange="populate('select1', 'select2')">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="Faculty of Arts, Humanities and Social Sciences"></option>
   <option value="Faculty of Computing, Engineering and the Built Environment"></option>
   <option value="Faculty of Life & Health Sciences"></option> 
   <option value="Ulster University Business School"></option> 
  </select>
  <hr/> Choose School:
  <select id="select2" name="select2"></select>
  <hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the text you want to display in between the option tags.

The value is not shown it isn't required but it usually is a shorter code that is  used to decide what was selected, makes your code cleaner. Example:

```js
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  if (s1.value == "0") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "schoolOfArt|School of Art", "schoolOfArtsAndHumanities|School of Arts and Humanities", "schoolOfCommunicationAndMedia|School of Communication and Media", "schoolOfEducation|School of Education", "schoolOfLaw|School of Law", "schoolOfAppliedSocialAndPolicySciences|School of Applied Social and Policy Sciences"];

  } else if (s1.value == "1") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "schoolOfComputing|School of Computing", "schoolOfComputingEngineeringAndIntelligentSystems|School of Computing, Engineering and Intelligent Systems", "schoolOfEngineering|School of Engineering", "School of Architecture and the Built Environment|schoolOfArchitectureAndTheBuiltEnvironment"];

  } else if (s1.value == "2") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "schoolOfBiomedicalSciences|School of Biomedical Sciences", "schoolOfGeographyEnvironmentalSciences|School of Geography & Environmental Sciences", "schoolOfHealthSciences|School of Health Sciences", "schoolOfNursing|School of Nursing", "schoolOfPharmacyAndPharmaceuticalSciences|School of Pharmacy & Pharmaceutical Sciences", "schoolOfPsychology|School of Psychology", "schoolOfSport|School of Sport"];

  } else if (s1.value == "3") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "departmentOfAccountingFinanceAndEconomics|Department of Accounting, Finance and Economics", "departmentOfGlobalBusinessAndEnterprise|Department of Global Business and Enterprise", "departmentOfHospitalityTourismManagement|Department of Hospitality & Tourism Management", "departmentOfManagementLeadershipAndMarketing|Department of Management, Leadership and Marketing"];
  }

  for (var option in optionArray) {
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Select your Faculty:</h2>
  <hr/> Choose Faculty:
  <select id="select1" name="select1" onchange="populate('select1', 'select2')">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="0">Faculty of Arts, Humanities and Social Sciences</option>
   <option value="1">Faculty of Computing, Engineering and the Built Environment</option>
   <option value="2">Faculty of Life & Health Sciences</option> 
   <option value="3">Ulster University Business School</option> 
  </select>
  <hr/> Choose School:
  <select id="select2" name="select2"></select>
  <hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: If this solution answered you question please mark it as accepted so others will be able to reference it.